# Simple MIPS assembly syntax that I'm confused over

Tags: assembly, mips

I have for example `$a0 = 0x1234`, If i mask this to get only the four list significant so simple looks like this `andi $t0,$a0,0xf`. Can i get the same result if i use `srl $t0,$a0,12`?

Comment: No, because the `srl` will give you the 4 **most significant** bits shifted down.

Comment: `0x1234>>12 == 0x0001`, `0x1234&0x000F == 0x0004`, `(0x1234&0x0F00)>>8 == 0x0002` <=> `(0x1234>>8)&0x000F == 0x0002` (`0x0F00>>8 == 0x000F`).

Comment: Are you sure? this is from my book, Left shifts always fill the least significant
bits with 0’s. However, right shifts can be either logical (0’s shift into the most
significant bits) or arithmetic (the sign bit shifts into the most significant bits).

Comment: http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html *"SRL -- Shift right logical"* (did surprise me a bit too, on many other platforms it's sll/slr, so the  last letter is indicative, here the second is) But even with left shift you would not get the same result `(short)(0x1234<<12) == 0x4000`, not `0x0004`.  (that right shift in my first example is "logical", so it's  not valid C/C++ example :/ ... I keep mixing them, when I think about ASM, where I have full control which shift is used, and I try to explain it with C/C++).

Comment: Thanks now i understand it well.